# ng-repeat not pushing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat directive to list a set of JSON data of the format

```
$scope.result=[
    {
        "id": 84,
        "resource": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Resource Planning",
            "description": "test"
        },
        "activity": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Activity Planning",
            "description": "test"
        }
    }
]
```

My usage of ng-repeat is like this..

```
 <div ng-repet="data in result">{{data.resource.name}} {{data.activity.name}}</div>
```

I'm able to display the name  ie., "Resouce Planning" and "Activity Planning".
But I can't push the data if I'm doing like this

```
$scope.result.push({resource.name:result.resource.name,activity.name:result.activity.name})
```

from the controller.
Is there any way to push the name which is inside the object. And to display/list the same using ng-repeat?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the question, but that's not how you build your javascript object. It should be something like:

```
$scope.result.push({
       resource: {
            name:   result.resource.name
       },
       activity: { 
            name:   result.activity.name
       }
})
```

Comment: Hi,Joao Leal.Thanks.But it's not pushing the data

Comment: It's kind of hard to guess without seeing how or in what context you're calling this.